# hide some future elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to hide a para on load

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/test.php",
    success:function(data){
            $('#div').html(data);}
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#para').hide();
})


</script>

<html>

<div id="div"> </div>
<input type="button" value="hide" id="btn">

</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo"<p id='para'> this is test </p>"
?>
```

What I am trying is to perform actions on future elements in client side and I am unable to do it ... any help.... ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a CSS rule that you add to any new elements which will have `display:none`.

This way, any new element will automatically have the CSS rules enforced on it. Once you want to display that element, just remove that CSS class..

```
echo "<p id='para' class='hide'> this is test </p>"
// here is the class------^
```

Now in your CSS file you can have this:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

To remove the class and make the paragraph visible, use this:

```
$( "#para" ).removeClass( "hide" );
```

---

You could also add this class via jQuery:

```
...
success:function( data ) {
  var element = $( data ); // assuming data is just raw HMTL
  element.addClass( "hide" );
  $( "#div" ).html( element.html() );
}
...
```

Comment: well it surely did hide but still having problem in making it visible again

Comment: Did you try removing that `hide` class? You can match all "hidden" elements with this selector - `$( ".hide" )`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a flag when `#btn` is clicked, and then hide the paragraph on AJAX success if the flag is set.